# disable retry attempts by dbcp connection pool

Tags: java, mysql, spring, connection-pooling, apache-commons-dbcp

I am using commons-dbcp connection pool, in case of Mysql connection loss the pool retries multiple times before "giving up". The downside is it waits toooo long before returning back. I need a way through which I can disable these retries so that I can handle the exception accordingly. Application is spring based.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can switch to c3p0 according to this blog http://psponcoding.blogspot.com/2012/02/database-connection-timed-out-but-how.html

Comment: yes I checked that option and I am hunting for similar paramater for dbcp-commons... I referred bench marks related to c3p0 and it is nice but I dont want to switch to c3p0 only because of this reason.